# How to hide all id's with a name that starts with

Tags: jquery

How can I tell jquery to hide all id's starting with `#ms_`?

What I've tried

```
$("#ms_" + $("*")).hide();
$("#ms_" + "*").hide();
$("#ms_" + *).hide();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try  this

```
$('[id^="ms_"]').hide();
```

see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) :

```
$('[id^="ms_"]').hide();
```